# K&R 3-4 Suggestion to make it better

Tags: c

I have solved the exercise , but I'm wondering can there be any better solutions to my code.The main function is not my work I just copied it to take the input,others are from the book

I was amazed that this part really worked 
**n = (~n) + 1**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void itoa(int n, char s[ ]);
void reverse(char s[]);


int main()
{

    char s[100];
     int x;
     while (1)
        {
        printf("Enter an integer value: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &x) != 1){ break; }
        printf("You entered the integer %d\n", x);
        itoa(x, s);
        printf("Converted string value is <%s>\n", s);
        }
       return 0;
}
void itoa(int n , char s[])
{
     int i , sign;
        if((sign = n ) < 0 )
             n = (~n) + 1 ;
            i = 0;
        do {
            s[i++] = n % 10 + '0';
        }
        while( (n /= 10) > 0  );
        if(sign < 0)
            s[i++] = '-';
        s[i] = '\0';
        reverse(s);
}
void reverse(char s[])
{
    int c , i , j ;
     for( i = 0 , j = strlen(s)-1 ; i < j ; i++,j--)
       c = s[i],s[i] = s[j],s[j]=c ;
}
```

Comment: This works for twos complement signed integers, but that is not mandated by the standard. Generally, you should avoid bit-operations on signed `int`.

Comment: Can you tell my reason why ? I'm still learning

Comment: For two's complement arithmetic, subtraction works by adding: `a - b == a + ~b + 1`. Your expression is a special case, subtraction from zero: `0 - b = ~ b + 1`. However, C-implementations could also use one's complement, where `-b = ~b`, or signed magnitude, where the a value is negative if the highest bit is set, but the magnitude of the value is unaffected by this bit. In either of these cases, your expression will no longer work.

Comment: You may want to post working code at codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Code has problems including `INT_MIN` and at least 7 other issues.  But this in not a code review site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview

Comment: @chux: `-INT_MIN` may be undefined behavior regardless of whether it is written in this peculiar way or as `abs(INT_MIN)`.

Comment: @EOF That is true, so code should not use `-INT_MIN` nor `abs(INT_MIN)`.  There are other coding choices that do not exhibit UB.  A simple method is not to negate the value when negative, but to negate the value when positive and then only use negative value in the loop.

Comment: @chux: Are you planning to go through all of stack overflow to comment on questions that contain unary minus on a signed integer type? You might be a while.

Comment: @EOF unary `-`  is never a problem on signed types when the value is not `type_MIN`.

Comment: @chux: Yes, but in general you can't be sure that the operand *isn't* `INT_MIN`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106403/discussion-between-chux-and-eof).

Answer (score 1):

According to n1570, 6.2.6.2 Integer types:

> 2 For signed integer types, the bits of the object representation
>   shall be divided into three groups: value bits, padding bits, and the
>   sign bit. ...... If the sign bit is zero, it shall not affect the
>   resulting value. If the sign bit is one, the value shall be modified
>   in one of the following ways:
>
> - the corresponding value with sign bit 0 is negated (sign and    magnitude);
> - the sign bit has the value -(2M) (two's complement);
> - the sign bit has the value -(2M- 1) (ones' complement).

That is, the bitwise representation of `int` is **unspecified**. It s true that many implementations use two's complement, making your `n = (~n) + 1 ;` effective. However, it's not portable because there are also implementations applying ones' complement or sign and magnitude.